# Return multiple lines in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x

```
d = {'U': 4, '_': 2, 'C': 2, 'K': 1, 'D': 4, 'T': 6, 'Q': 1, 'V': 2, 'A': 9, 'F': 2, 'O': 8, 'J': 1, 'I': 9, 'N': 6, 'P': 2, 'S': 4, 'M': 2, 'W': 2, 'E': 12, 'Z': 1, 'G': 3, 'Y': 2, 'B': 2, 'L': 4, 'R': 6, 'X': 1, 'H': 2}
    def __str__(self):
    omgekeerd = {}
    for sleutel, waarde in self.inhoud.items():
        letters = omgekeerd.get(waarde, '')
        letters += sleutel
        omgekeerd[waarde] = letters
    for aantal in sorted(omgekeerd):
        return '{}: {}'.format(aantal, ''.join(sorted(omgekeerd[aantal])))
```

I need to return the value, followed by a ':' and then followed by every letter that has that value.

The problem is that when I use return, it only returns one value instead of every vale on a new line.

I can't use print() because that is not supported by the method **str**(self).

Comment: It'd be nice if u translated your code into english (parts which are not in english)

Comment: omgekeerd is the name of my dictionary, sleutel is key and waarde is value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
>   be returned to the function caller.

I believe that your code is terminated too early because of wrong usage of return statement.

What you could do is to store what you would like to return in a seperate list/dictionary and then when everything is done, you can return the new dict/list that you've stored the results in.

If I understood you correctly; This is what might be looking for:

```
def someFunc():
    d = {'U': 4, '_': 2, 'C': 2, 'K': 1, 'D': 4, 'T': 6, 'Q': 1, 'V': 2, 'A': 9,
    'F': 2, 'O': 8, 'J': 1, 'I': 9, 'N': 6, 'P': 2, 'S': 4, 'M': 2, 'W': 2, 'E': 12,
    'Z': 1, 'G': 3, 'Y': 2, 'B': 2, 'L': 4, 'R': 6, 'X': 1, 'H': 2}

    result = {}
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        result[value] = [k for k,v in d.iteritems() if v == value]

    return result

# call function and iterate over given dictionary
for key, value in someFunc().iteritems():
    print key, value
```

Result:

```
1 ['K', 'J', 'Q', 'X', 'Z']
2 ['C', 'B', 'F', 'H', 'M', 'P', 'W', 'V', 'Y', '_']
3 ['G']
4 ['D', 'L', 'S', 'U']
6 ['N', 'R', 'T']
8 ['O']
9 ['A', 'I']
12 ['E']
```

Comment: I forgot to add this line in my code: def __str__(self). I need to solve my problem under this mehod so the print function won't work I think.

Comment: send the whole class(the python file), i will edit it

Comment: class Zak:
    '''
    >>> zak = Zak('IAMDIETINGIEATQUINCEJELLYLOTSOFGROUNDMAIZEGIVESVARIETYICOOKRHUBARBANDSODAWEEPANEWORPUTONEXTRAFLESH__')
    >>> zak.inhoud
    {'U': 4, '_': 2, 'C': 2, 'K': 1, 'D': 4, 'T': 6, 'Q': 1, 'V': 2, 'A': 9, 'F': 2, 'O': 8, 'J': 1, 'I': 9, 'N': 6, 'P': 2, 'S': 4, 'M': 2, 'W': 2, 'E': 12, 'Z': 1, 'G': 3, 'Y': 2, 'B': 2, 'L': 4, 'R': 6, 'X': 1, 'H': 2}
    >>> print(zak)
    1: JKQXZ
    2: BCFHMPVWY_
    3: G
    4: DLSU
    6: NRT
    8: O
    9: AI
    12: E

Comment: class Zak:
    '''
    >>> zak = Zak('IAMDIETINGIEATQUINCEJELLYLOTSOFGROUNDMAIZEGIVESVARIETYICOOKRHUBARBANDSODAWEEPANEWORPUTONEXTRAFLESH__')
    >>> zak.inhoud
    {'U': 4, '_': 2, 'C': 2, 'K': 1, 'D': 4, 'T': 6, 'Q': 1, 'V': 2, 'A': 9, 'F': 2, 'O': 8, 'J': 1, 'I': 9, 'N': 6, 'P': 2, 'S': 4, 'M': 2, 'W': 2, 'E': 12, 'Z': 1, 'G': 3, 'Y': 2, 'B': 2, 'L': 4, 'R': 6, 'X': 1, 'H': 2}
    >>> print(zak)
    1: JKQXZ
    2: BCFHMPVWY_
    3: G
    4: DLSU
    6: NRT
    8: O
    9: AI
    12: E

Comment: def __str__(self):
        omgekeerd = {}
        for sleutel, waarde in self.inhoud.items():
            letters = omgekeerd.get(waarde, '')
            letters += sleutel
            omgekeerd[waarde] = letters
        for aantal in sorted(omgekeerd):
            return '{}: {}'.format(aantal, ''.join(sorted(omgekeerd[aantal])))

Comment: use pastebin.com please

Comment: Ok I posted it on pastebin.com

Comment: ... and where's the link ?

Comment: Now iam confused... Is `d = {}` going to be modified outside of class when a new instance of it is created? and what's to be done with `letterreeks` ?

Comment: Please prodive more info on what you're trying to achieve. For instance; does `d = {...}` always have constants as shown in the question above? Are you supposed to find out amount of letters in given string based on `d= { }` ?

Comment: Yes I need to return every value on a new line with each value followed by every letter that has the same value

Comment: Here you go (Upvote the answer if this is what you're looking for): https://pastebin.com/3KYBkv3W here's a preview of the test result : `WIBBLYWOBBLY` = `{1: ['I', 'O'], 2: ['L', 'W', 'Y'], 4: ['B']}`

Comment: btw, if you wish to make the result from `__str__` readable, use this : `return '\n'.join([str(x)+": "+' '.join([y for y in result[x]]) for x in result])` in your `__str__` function